# Utility with unredirectable output (Windows)

Tags: windows, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

I am using a Microsoft command-line utility to perform a task.  The specific details of what the utility does and the task it performs are, I think, relatively unimportant.  This is what is important:

The command-line utility emits text to the console window.  I cannot figure out how to redirect this text to a file, though I have tried every approach I could find through research.  It seems the utility is using some strange OS function call that causes text to be printed in a way that is not subject to the normal means of redirection.  I am using a Windows 7 cmd.exe console window.

None of these constructs redirect the text output in question:

```
util.exe >log.txt
util.exe 2>err.txt
util.exe >log.txt 2>&1
util.exe 1>log.txt 2>err.txt
util.exe 1>log.txt 2>err.txt 3>3.txt 4>4.txt 5>5.txt 6>6.txt 7>7.txt 8>8.txt 9>9.txt
```

Confused about that last one?  [Turns out there are 10 output streams in Windows-land](https://web.archive.org/web/20160423045544/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), but that didn't get the job done either.

I can copy the text using the console window's Edit>Mark select-and-copy functionality, but I need to capture this program's output in a headless way so that it can be automated.

I cannot find any OS function call that specifically prints to the console bypassing redirection.  Does such a function exist?  How does this utility manage to circumvent redirection?  And what means could I use to capture this utility's output?

I also tried DbgView, thinking maybe that might contain the output messages, but it did not.

The utility is not a graphical utility.  It is pretty obviously a text-mode program, probably written in C or C++.  It was written by Microsoft.

Comment: I've seen (and given up on answering) SO questions asking how to write such a utility...

Comment: What utility is this? (Since it's written by MS)

Comment: The utility is SpeechLMBuilder.exe from the [Microsoft Windows Dictation Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23262).

Comment: WriteConsoleOutput() cannot be redirected.  Some odds they used it to bypass the blasted 8-bit code page restrictions imposed by the console.  Nothing you can do about that of course.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question, and for the ten output streams - it's good to learn something when reading a question!

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that while the existence of the extra standard streams is documented, ther doesn't appear to be any documentation on how to either set or use them from an application.  Apparently they're either specific to `cmd.exe` or they use undocumented Win32 functionality.

Comment: ... after some more experimentation I've concluded that the extra standard streams only exist within the context of the batch processor and are not inherited by subprocesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing particularly magical about it.  Although the C library defaults to sending output to the standard output handle, there's no obligation for a program to do so; you can always open your own handle to the console output device (`CONOUT$`) instead.

See the documentation on [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information about console devices.

In terms of capturing the output, you may be able to do something with [`ReadConsoleOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends, but it isn't straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to explain it.  I will investigate whether I can capture this text with ReadConsoleOutput.

Comment: Overriding standard streams even works in pure batch: `( echo hello>con ) >x.y`

Comment: [Pseudoconsole API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creating-a-pseudoconsole-session) makes `ReadConsoleOutput` obsolete.

Comment: @zett42, thanks, that's good to know.  I'm going through my existing answers now to see where this might be relevant.