# Getting program output not working for certain programs

Tags: python, windows, io, stdout, command-line-interface

I am trying to get the output of a Windows CLI program called `CheckLog` (which ships with `Exact Audio Copy`), and I have searched high and low for a solution to my problem, but I can't for the life of me get the output (returns `''` or `b''`). It actually does work with other apps (tested `nfi` from the Microsoft OEM Support Tools pack), so I don't know what the problem could be... Here is the most recent code I tested:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os, subprocess

checklog_path = os.environ['programfiles'] + '\\Exact Audio Copy\\CheckLog.exe'
log_path = 'C:\EAClog.log'

EAC = subprocess.Popen([checklog_path, log_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

EACoutput = EAC.communicate()[0]
```

I have also tried this however:

```
EACoutput = EAC.stdout.read()
```

Any ideas? I'm running a fresh install of Python 3.4 (installed last night) on Windows XP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Utility with unredirectable output (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915834/utility-with-unredirectable-output-windows)

Answer (score 1):

A few points on the topic of capturing the output of the `CheckLog.exe` program from Exact Audio Copy:

1) `CheckLog.exe` outputs to stdout.

2) Redirecting output also fails in the Windows shell:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Exact Audio Copy>CheckLog.exe %logpath%
Log Integrity Checker   (C) 2010 by Andre Wiethoff

1. Log entry has no checksum!

C:\Program Files (x86)\Exact Audio Copy>CheckLog.exe %logpath% 1> %temp%\stdout.
txt

C:\Program Files (x86)\Exact Audio Copy>dir %temp%\stdout.txt
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1B3A-F950

 Directory of C:\Users\marius\AppData\Local\Temp

04.09.2014  08:35                 0 stdout.txt
           1 File(s)              0 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  171.767.508.992 bytes free

C:\Program Files (x86)\Exact Audio Copy>CheckLog.exe %logpath% 2> %temp%\stderr.
txt
Log Integrity Checker   (C) 2010 by Andre Wiethoff

1. Log entry has no checksum!

C:\Program Files (x86)\Exact Audio Copy>CheckLog.exe %logpath% | cat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Exact Audio Copy>echo 'hello world' | cat
'hello world'
```

Answer (score 0):

Three points:

1) in Python, the backslash is a "quote" character -- this tends to mess up Windows paths.  Use Python raw strings -- ex: `r"c:\\beer.exe"`

2) subprocess.check_output()` is the easiest and most reliable way to run a command and get its output.

3) in Python you can mash strings together to get file paths, but it can be tricky to get right.  Use `os.path.join()` to simplify code. Perk: it's cross-platform.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os, subprocess

checklog_path = os.path.join(
    os.environ['programfiles'],
    r'Exact Audio Copy\CheckLog.exe', # no leading backslash
    )
log_path = r'C:\EAClog.log'

EACoutput = subprocess.check_output(
    [checklog_path, log_path], 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )
```

Comment: The `os.path.join` function returns `C:\Exact Audio Copy\CheckLog.exe` rather than `C:\Program Files\Exact Audio Copy\CheckLog.exe` (like it should, on my system) for some reason. Also, `check_output()` does not permit an stdout argument so that throws an error.

Comment: @user966939 I've edited the code, please take another look, and mark the answer Accepted if it works for you.

Comment: Yup, the path comes out as expected now. But it still fails to collect the output from CheckLog.

Comment: @user966939 does CheckLog write to stderr or stdout?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what it writes to.. It's not open source (and I have no idea if it's even possible to see somehow).

Comment: Shouldn't `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` be in `check_output()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58823/discussion-between-shavenwarthog-and-user966939).