# Console output redirect issue

Tags: c#, windows, gcc, gnat

I have an issue with console output redirection (wrote in C#).
With "cmd.exe" and any arguments (like "dir") everything works just fine, but with "gnatmake.exe" or "gcc.exe" nothing! I don't see an output and the commands I gave to these programs aren't working (source code isn't compilling)! I've tried with and without arguments -- nothing!

```
console = new Process();

// The path is correct, I've checked!
console.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\MinGW\bin\gnatmake.exe";

// cmd.exe works perfectly!
//console.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";

// gnatmake.exe isn't working even without arguments
console.StartInfo.Arguments = currFile;
console.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
console.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
console.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ConsoleOutputHandler);
console.Start();
console.BeginOutputReadLine();

void ConsoleOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs recieved)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recieved.Data))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(recieved.Data);
    }
}
```

I've tried something else:

```
console = new Process();
console.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\MinGW\bin\gnatmake.exe";
console.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
console.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
console.Start();

StreamWriter sr = console.StandardInput;
sr.WriteLine(currFile);
sr.Close();

string str = console.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
console.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Still doesn't work with "gnatmake.exe", but works with "cmd.exe"!

But then I've just wrote this:

```
Process.Start(@"D:\MinGW\bin\gnatmake.exe", currFile);
```

and it worked, compiled the file but with this function I can't have an output! What's wrong with "gnatmake.exe" and "gcc.exe"? How to do it properly?
Thanks for answers!

Comment: Does it work if you don't set `CreateNoWindow = true` ?

Comment: Doesn't work! I've tried to comment this line and replace true with false -- nothing!

Comment: What happens if you run `gnatmake.exe` with redirected output at the command line, i.e., with the command `gnatmake.exe | more` ?

Comment: I've tried this `gnatmake.exe hello.adb > test.txt`. File `test.txt` was created but it was empty! Source code was compiled properly and I still saw output in command line window.

Comment: Sounds like `gnatmake` is writing directly to the console rather than respecting the standard output.  There isn't much you can practically do about this, although since this is open source I guess you could fix it yourself if it is important enough to you to justify the effort.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915834/utility-with-unredirectable-output-windows

Comment: Well, I won't be doing anything with `gnatmake`, but I will examine source code of `Gnat Programming Studio`. As far as I remember, this program could read the output of compiler. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

I've made this work! I've fount parameter `-eS` for `gnatmake` and it worked in command line (`gnatmake.exe -eS hello.adb > test.txt`).
For some reason (who may tell me why?) it didn't work in this code:

```
console = new Process();
console.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\MinGW\bin\gnatmake.exe";
console.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
console.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
console.Start();

StreamWriter sw = console.StandardInput;
sw.WriteLine("-eS " + currFile);
sw.Close();

string str = console.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
console.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

But it worked without redirection of standard input (maybe input isn't standard at all, as well as output?):

```
console = new Process();
console.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\MinGW\bin\gnatmake.exe";
console.StartInfo.Arguments = "-eS " + currFile;
console.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
console.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
console.Start();

string str = console.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
console.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

So, I have an answer on at least one of my questions. Thanks to `Harry Johnston` for responding!

Update:
I've realised, that this code give me only `gnatmake`'s output. `gnatmake` is calling another programs for it's work. But I've found a simple solution!
`gnatmake hello.adb 2> test.txt` is doing what I need. I can get output from test.txt.
I've read that `2>` is getting `stderr` output. I've tried to get error output in C#, but what I've got was only a list of `gnatmake`'s parameters! I guess I don't wanna bother with it, reading text from a file is good enough for me.